# Is it safe to assume that the program_id passed via the solana runtime Entrypoint cannot be Forged

Tags: anchor-lang, runtime, native-programs

I am writing a program of which I cannot know the program ID ahead of time for several non-trivial reasons.

I am curious whether or not it is safe to assume the safety of the program_id passed via the entry-point.

my deep dive so far indicates it is safe, but I just want some external feedback before continuing with what could maybe prove to be a detrimentally false assumption.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of the program entrypoint at https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/developing-rust#program-entrypoint, you'll see:

> This entrypoint takes a generic byte array which contains the serialized program parameters (program id, accounts, instruction data, etc...)

And you'll get the full spec at https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/overview#input-parameter-serialization, which includes the program's pubkey at the end.

If this is ever broken, the network will have huge issues!